# How to use the new MediaStream API to get audio FFT?

Tags: javascript, html5-audio, mediastream

In MDN documentation, `navigator.getUserMedia` is marked as deprecated and `navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia` is recommended instead.

But there's absolutely no useful documentation on it.

I have an old script that used to get FFT of audio to draw spectrograph, like this:

[image]

I now want to do similar thing. I want to get FFT of the audio, perform some math operations on it, then play it back.

So, following the new API, I figured out this:

```
const media = await navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia({ audio: true });
const audio_track = media.getAudioTracks()[0];
```

This shows an `AudioStreamTrack` if I log it in console:

```
AudioStreamTrack {
    kind: "audio",
    id: "{93774f91-7eae-4fe8-8183-d7adee83174b}",
    label: "default: Microphone (Realtek High Definition Audio)",
    enabled: true,
    muted: false,
    onmute: null,
    onunmute: null,
    readyState: "live",
    onended: null
}
```

There is absolutely no documentation on this class. There's also no documentation on getting any sound from `MediaStreamTrack` which is the parent class.

So how to get FFT samples from sound recorded by `MediaStream` API?

Comment: Perhaps, if you have not already seen this, it might help?! https://medium.com/@bryanjenningz/how-to-record-and-play-audio-in-javascript-faa1b2b3e49b